# NASM Array User input

Tags: arrays, nasm

section .data
num1 dd 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
msg dd "Value=%d",10,0

section .text
extern _printf
global _main

_main:
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov eax,10
mov ebx,num1 ;point bx to first number
mov ecx,0 ;load 0

```
loop:

;store the value because external function like printf modify the value
push ebx
push eax
push ecx

;print the value stored on stack
    push DWORD [ebx]
push msg
    call _printf
;clear the stack
add esp,8

;restore thses values
pop ecx
pop eax
pop ebx
;increment the counter
inc ecx
;add 4 byte to ebx
add ebx,4
;compare value stored in ecx and eax
cmp ecx,eax
jne loop

    
;destroy the stack
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp

    ret
```

I wanted to write a similar NASM code from the one above but the numbers should be from the user input and user should be ask if how many numbers to input.